# breaking out of while loops

Tags: python, while-loop

So this is a simplified version of my bigger code (there is some unnecessary bits that makes more sense in my main code), and I cannot seem to understand why it neither breaks out of the playing nor the fight loops:

```
fight = True
a = "enemy"
t = "" 
ccd = False,False
playing = True

def lvl():
    playing = True
    fight = True    
    while fight:
        if a == "enemy":
            t = "enemy"
        else:
            if a == "enemy":
                t = "enemy"
            else:
                t = "player"
        while t == "enemy":
            print ("enemy attacks player")
            t = "player"
        while t == "player":
            if ccd == (False , False):
                fight = False
                playing = False
                turn = "no one"
            t = "enemy"

fight = True
while playing:
    fight = True
    lvl()
while not playing:
    print ("no")
```

Comment: When you do `playing = False`, you're modifying a local variable (local to the function `lvl`) which has no effect on the global variable `playing`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program actually is breaking out of the "fight" loop, but it is sent right back in because the playing loop is still running.

The reason why you are not breaking out of the playing loop is that your "playing" variable is local, not global. As such, when you change the variable in the function it doesn't change the one in main (even though they have the same name), which you are using to control the while loop. A possible solution for this would be to return "playing" at the end of your function. Here is some modified code that should suit your purposes:

'''

```
fight = True
a = "enemy"
t = "" 
ccd = False,False
playing = True

def lvl():
    playing = True
    fight = True    
    while fight:
        if a == "enemy":
            t = "enemy"
        else:
            t = "player"
        while t == "enemy":
            print ("enemy attacks player")
            t = "player"
        while t == "player":
            if ccd == (False , False):
                fight = False
                playing = False
            t = "enemy"
    return playing
fight = True
while playing:
    fight = True
    playing = lvl()
while not playing:
    print ("no")
```

'''

Answer (score -1):

To have lvl() affect the global variable, you must do the following:

```
def lvl():
    global playing
    playing = True
```